# How to insert images in HTML on chromebook caret editor

Tags: html, image, import, chromium, google-chrome-os

Hi I am programming a website using HTML and I am using caret text editor as my Chromebook doesn't support Linux. I am unable to import images from my files app. The HTML program and the image is in the same folder. My code:
`<html><head><title>project</title></head><body><img src="qw1.png"></body></html>`
I am curious whether it is possible to import images using caret and if yes how to specify the path of image. Thank u

Comment: when I open the file its plain white screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image is not displayed even if you do the following, I think the image is empty.

[image]